# Sequelize table id clash

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sequelize.js

In my simple CRUD app (using sequelize) I have an odd issue where after updating my database models then importing my backup data in, any new additions begin from `{id: 1}` when I have 50 rows imported back in. Is there a way for sequelize to look at the highest `id` value and increment from there instead of starting at 1 again after an update? Has anyone encountered this? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on who is generating id's: DBMS or Sequelize. If it's DBMS probably it means you should backup data with sequences (like in PostgreSQL). Please indicate who is generating id's and what DBMS you are using

Comment: Thanks for the response @Anatoly - I am using PostgreSQL. I have an id key on my sequelize model   
`id: {
type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
primaryKey: true,
autoIncrement: true
},` like so which I had previously read would help to avoid these collisions. Not the case.

Comment: `autoIncrement: true` means you have `SERIAL` column as PK and that's why you have autocreated sequence for this column. Take a look at sequences to find a sequence related with the PK